# In Carrierwave how to create a version only when needed? Not when uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have setup an uploader to upload a bunch of photos to an album. Then I let the user to select 4 images for the album cover. After they select it, I need to generate a smaller version of the photos. Only the selected 4. How can I do this?

Basically I need a way to generate image versions after the main upload. We can use something like refile. But the problem is, I also need it to create some versions while uploading!

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this?  If so, could you share?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Building off @karlingen's answer:

*I'm going to assume there is a 'selected' boolean value on the table for the image records.*

```
# picture.rb
belongs_to :my_model
scope :chosen, -> { where(selected: true) }
```

Set the version you want to display to the user to select in the Carrierwave Uploader, along with the versions you want after the album is selected

```
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

# Original Version
version :thumb do
  process resize_to_fill: [50, 50]
end

# Processed Later
versions :large_album, if: :is_selected? do
  process resize_to_fill: [500, 500]
end
versions :medium_album, if: :is_selected? do
  process resize_to_fill: [400, 400]
end
versions :small_album, if: :is_selected? do
  process resize_to_fill: [300, 300]
end

private

# Check if it is selected
def is_selected?(picture)
  picture.uploader.model.selected
end
```

> [Conditional versions](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#conditional-versions)
>
> Occasionally you want to restrict the creation of versions on certain
>   properties within the model or based on the picture itself.

Then when the user selects the album photos they want to use you can call a manual create versions call in the controller on the selected albums:

```
my_model.pictures.chosen.each do |picture|
    picture.image.recreate_versions!(:large_album, :medium_album, :small_album)
end
```

> [Recreating versions](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#recreating-versions)
>
> You might come to a situation where you want to retroactively change a
>   version or add a new one. You can use the recreate_versions! method to
>   recreate the versions from the base file. This uses a naive approach
>   which will re-upload and process the specified version or all
>   versions, if none is passed as an argument.
>
> When you are generating random unique filenames you have to call save!
>   on the model after using recreate_versions!. This is necessary because
>   recreate_versions! doesn't save the new filename to the database.
>   Calling save! yourself will prevent that the database and file system
>   are running out of sync..... Or on a mounted uploader

*You might also consider tying this into an after_update function.*

Answer (score 2):

Simply drop this into your uploader model:

```
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

version :thumb do
  process :resize_to_fill => [50, 50]
end
```

Then inside your view, instead of calling `my_model.picture` you can do:

```
<%= image_tag my_model.picture_url(:thumb) if my_model.picture? %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Cloudinary with carrierwave to do that:

## Installation

To install Cloudinary was pretty simple. First add it and Carrier wave to your gemfile.

```
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'cloudinary'
```

Then add the security settings for Cloudinary. These are found on your Cloudinary dashboard.

```
# config/cloudinary.yml

development:
  cloud_name: "sample"
  api_key: "874837483274837"
  api_secret: "a676b67565c6767a6767d6767f676fe1"

production:
  cloud_name: "sample"
  api_key: "874837483274837"
  api_secret: "a676b67565c6767a6767d6767f676fe1"
```

Now you are ready to add your CarrierWave uploader.

```
rails g uploader avatar
```

And add carrier wave to the new uploader. Also comment out the storage and store_dir lines as you aren't using local storage, but Cloudinary.

app/uploaders/avatar_uploader.rb

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  # def store_dir
  #   "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  # end

end
```

Super!

## CarrierWave Setup

Now we can treat it like a normal CarrierWave setup. First add a migration to add the uploader to the model.

```
rails g migration add_avatar_to_user avatar:string
rake db:migrate
```

Now to add it into our model, form and view.

```
# app/models/user.rb
attr_accessible :avatar

mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader


# app/views/users/_form.html.erb
<legend>Avatar</legend>
<%= f.file_field :avatar %>


# app/views/users/show.html.erb
<% unless @user.avatar_url.nil? %><%= image_tag @user.avatar_url %><br /><% end %>
```

Great! Now we are really rolling. You'll note that your images in the HTML pull from res.cloudinary.com rather than your app's URL, which is nice to save on bandwidth.

## Transformations and Resizing

I also have gone and resized the images. I have two sizes, one for their profile and a mini one for when they show up in the users index. You can do all your transformations back in the image uploader. The :eager portion tells Cloudinary to do the resize at initial image save, rather than the first time the image is loaded.

```
# app/uploaders/avatar_uploader.rb

  version :display do
    process :eager => true
    process :resize_to_fill => [200, 200, :north]
  end

  version :thumbnail do
    process :eager => true
    process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  end
```

You can then easily call the resized image from within the views.

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar_url(:display) %>
```

Cloudinary has a host of other transformation features, both all that CarrierWave supports and some that it does not. For more info check out their documentation.

Have fun with all those images!